# build sucess but publish failed

Tags: build, publish

I encountered a similar issue when I had to publish my project. I fixed it by following the steps below:

**Step 1:** Clean and rebuild the solution.

**Step 2:** Remove all files from the bin and obj folders, then repeat Step 1.

**Step 3:** Run Visual Studio as an administrator, build, and try to publish, but encounter a similar result as before.

**Step 4:** Finally, I found the actual cause of the error. It was being thrown from my project's document folder. So, I simply **hide it from File Explorer** --> **refresh the project** --> **clean and rebuild the solution** -->  and then **publish the web app**.

This approach led to success.

I have fix it by my own approches